# How to find the last activity (event or task) related to an object record?

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, event, activity

In my **contact** object i have to update fields  based on the last activity. If the last activity  is an event ,update the field with event details and if it is task ,then with task details.
How to check the last activity whether it is an event or task?

Could someone help ?

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by querying the Task and Event objects and ordering the results based on the activity date.

Here's an example SOQL query to retrieve the last activity, whether it's an event or task, for a specific record (e.g., an Account):

```
SELECT Subject, ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId = 'Your_Record_Id' ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query selects the subject, activity date of the task associated with a specific record. It orders the results by activity date in descending order and limits the results to only one record, which gives you the latest task for the specified record.

Similarly, you can query the Event object to get the last event for a record:

```
SELECT Subject, ActivityDate FROM Event WHERE WhatId = 'Your_Record_Id' ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

//**Update Sobject taking example as Account**

```
if (!fetchedTasklist.isEmpty() || !fetchedEventlist.isEmpty()) {
Account accToUpdate = new Account(Id = yourAccountId);

if (!fetchedTasklist.isEmpty()) {
    // Update the Account field based on the last task
    accToUpdate.YourCustomField__c = 'Last activity was a Task: ' + fetchedTasklist[0].Subject;
} else if (!recentEventlist.isEmpty()) {
    // Update the Account field based on the last event
    accToUpdate.YourCustomField__c = 'Last activity was an Event: ' + recentEventlist[0].Subject;
}

// Update the Account record
update accToUpdate;
```

Comment: This also doesn't really answer the question. It does nothing to determine whether the last activity was a task or an event. Suppose a Contact has 1 of each, and the event is the most recent activity. This code would incorrectly say that the last activity was a task.

Comment: I've removed the other comment as it does seem to be legit. Arvind can you address Dererk's comment? As he says, it doesn't actually answer the quesiton properly

Comment: tl;dr: Don't use this answer. It is wrong